# Find Element in protractor plugin

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I want to add extra code before each step in my protractor tests. So I decided to write a small plugin and use one of the hooks like "waitForPromise".

https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/5.1.2/lib/plugins.ts#L163

I have a problem to get to any protractor or browser instances. Here is the code example.

```
var protractor = require('protractor');
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

module.exports = {
    waitForPromise: function(){
        //this add 3 second after each promise(work fine)
        browser.sleep(3000);

        //this doesn't work. looks like it goes to endless promise execution.
        return browser.wait(function () {
            return $('body').getAttribute('class').then(function (attr) {
                console.log(attr);
            });
        },3000);
    }
};
```

**UPDATE:**
I have updated my example according to research.

**UPDATE:** If anybody knows why this code doesn't work, please don't hesitate to answer.

```
waitForPromise: function(){
    return $('body').isPresent().then(function (val) {
        console.log('present',val);
    });
}
```

If anyone interested in working solution of "waitForPromise", you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45144668/before-each-step-event-emitter-in-protractor-to-handle-animation/45239516#45239516).

Answer (score 0):

You can use locators in protractor by one of the following ways:

```
element(by.css('app-title'));
```

or the short hand of above is:

```
$('app-title');
```

You are using both so I think that is the issue. Please refer the official page of using locators in protractor - http://www.protractortest.org/#/locators

Comment: sorry for that mistake, I have tried so many ways to select element. Both ways not working. Test hangs on that step like it can't resolve the promise somehow. I have updated the thread.

Comment: which version of Node.js are you using?

Comment: Node version: v6.11.0